# What is the difference between istio_request_bytes_count and istio_request_bytes_sum?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

Can someone briefly explain what is the difference between `istio_request_bytes_count` and `istio_request_bytes_sum`?. And why is the "istio_request_bytes" standard metric is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Istio Standard Metrics](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/metrics/) notes that `istio_request_bytes` is a `DISTRIBUTION` type metric.  In Prometheus, this would appear as a [histogram metric](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram).  So, you should see three metrics:

- `istio_request_bytes_count` is the number of requests
- `istio_request_bytes_sum` is the total number of bytes, added together across all requests
- `istio_request_bytes_bucket{le="1024"}` is the total number of requests where the request size is 1 KiB or smaller

You can calculate the average request size by dividing the sum by the count.  You can also use Prometheus functions like [`histogram_quantile()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile) to calculate the median (50th-percentile) size.

This also applies to the other standard metrics.  A common thing to measure is 95th-percentile latency ("p95"); how long does it take 95% of the requests to execute, where the remaining 5% take longer than this?  `histogram_quantile(0.95, istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket[1h])` could compute this over the most recent hour.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please let me know is there any documentation from istio to find information like this in detail?

Comment: The first two links in my answer are to the relevant Istio and Prometheus documentation, respectively.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Can u help interpret this metric thats from the standard Istio dashboard - (histogram_quantile(0.50, sum(irate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter=~"source", connection_security_policy!="mutual_tls"}[$__rate_interval])) by (source_workload, source_workload_namespace, le)) / 1000) . Why are we diving it by 1000 for milliseconds ?